# The start value of integer "x" should be how many?

Tags: javascript, function, sequence

this is a simple function:

```
function sequence(a,b,c,d){
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    for(var i = a; i<=b; i++){
        y = eval(c);
        x = eval(d);
    }
    return x;
}
```

a&b must be an integer and c&d must be a string

this code gets the sum of 1 to 5:

```
sequence(1,5,"i","x+y")
```

result:

```
15
```

this code gets the product of 1 to 5:

```
sequence(1,5,"i","x*y")
```

result:

```
0
```

the problem is at "`var x = 0;`", the value of "`x`" should be how many?

```
sequence(1,5,"i","x+y") >>> 15
sequence(1,5,"i","x*y") >>> 0
sequence(1,5,"i","x-y") >>> -15
sequence(1,5,"i","x/y") >>> 0
sequence(1,5,"i","x**y") >>> 0
sequence(1,5,"i","x%y") >>> 0
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is called [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The initial value must be passed in as there is no one single initial value that fits all purposes.

Comment: in ```sequence(1,5,"i","x*y")```what's the "i" stands for???
What should be the result for each call??? The number after >>> ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that when you write this block that the number following >>> is not the expected result, otherwise I don't understand your question!

```
sequence(1,5,"i","x+y") >>> 15
sequence(1,5,"i","x*y") >>> 0
sequence(1,5,"i","x-y") >>> -15
sequence(1,5,"i","x/y") >>> 0
sequence(1,5,"i","x**y") >>> 0
sequence(1,5,"i","x%y") >>> 0
```

note that % stands for modulo not for percentage, I don't know what you expect as result there!

I don't understand what the "i" stands for in the parameters.
There' a problem with the ** operator when you use some values.
I commented that in the snippet bellow.

Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk.

It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval().

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Here is a snippet that works only if a<b, i will add another snippet below that works if a>b too.

```js
        "use strict";
        function operationFromAtoB(a,b,c){
            // You don't have to declare x here
            var y = "";
            for (var i = a; i <= b; i++) {
                if(i != b){
                    y += (i.toString() + c );
                }else{
                    y += (i.toString())
                }
            }
            var result = y + " = " + eval(y);
            return result;
        }
        
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"+"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"*"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"-"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"/"));
        // Next line throws NaN or Infinity if out of range
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(2,4,"**"));
        // 1**2**3**4**5 = NaN
        // 2**3**4**5 = Infinity
        // 2**3**4 = 2.4178516392292583e+24
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"%"));
```

Here there's a snippet that works if a<b AND if a>b :

```js
        function operationFromAtoB(a,b,c){
            var result = "";
            var y = "";
            if(a<b){
                for (var i = a; i <= b; i++) {
                    if(i != b){
                        y += (i.toString() + c );
                    }else{
                        y += (i.toString())
                    }
                }
            }else{
                for (var j = a; j >= b; j--) {
                    if(j != b){
                        y += (j.toString() + c );
                    }else{
                        y += (j.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
            result = y + " = " + eval(y);
            return result;
        }
    
        console.log("a<b !!!")
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"+"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"*"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"-"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(1,5,"/"));
        console.log("a>b !!!")
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(5,1,"+"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(5,1,"*"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(5,1,"-"));
        console.log(operationFromAtoB(5,1,"/"));
```